# Sql Server CTE Parent Child recursive

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have following table structure:

```
create table Test(
  ParentId int,
  ChildId int
 )

insert into Test(ParentId, ChildId)
select 1, NULL
union
select 1, 2
union
select 1, 3
union
select 2, NULL
union
select 2, 5
union
select 5, 6
union 
select 6, 5
union 
select 6, 8
```

I'm trying to **build a result set of all parent child DIRECT and INDIRECT relationships**. So suppose I pass the parameter of ParentID = 2, I would like the result set to return exactly as below:

```
ParentId    ChildId
-------------------
2           NULL
2           5
5           6
6           8
1           2
```

So basically this **shows all possible links** that can be found in one table for Parent ID = 2.
Starting off with Parent itself, it has Child Id which then has other relations with Child Id 6. Also the parent Id 2 falls under parent id 1 which should also show up in result set. Please note the relationship could expand to **N number of levels**. I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve here, if not then please let me know so that I can explain more clearly.

So far I have come up with below recursive query but it throws an error which is stated below:

```
DECLARE @ID INT = 2

;WITH MyCTE
AS (
    SELECT ParentId
        ,ChildId
    FROM Test
    WHERE ParentId = @ID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.ParentId
        ,Test.ChildId
    FROM Test
    INNER JOIN MyCTE T ON Test.ParentID = T.ChildId
    WHERE Test.ParentID IS NOT NULL
    )
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE

Error:
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion
```

I have put up the code on [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/303e8/10) for you guys to test and try.

I would really appreciate anyone who guides and helps me in achieving my desired result.

Comment: You have a circular references in your data. 5 is parent to 6 and 6 is parent to 5. That makes the recursion go round and round and ... Is this what your data actually look like?

Comment: And besides that circular reference - what's the conditions for getting (Parent, Child) 1, 2 in the end of the result?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson yes this is how data will look like as there many types of relationships that can exist between two persons.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I have not setup the condition yet. I am looking for something generic that can return such a result set.

Comment: Did you find an answer here?  If @GriGrim didnt work for you, can you post your own solution? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

As #Mikael Eriksson said: "You have a circular references in your data. 5 is parent to 6 and 6 is parent to 5."

Also in recursive part you output `ParentId` from previous step, not from just found rows.

```
declare @Test table (ParentId int, ChildId int)

insert into @Test (ParentId, ChildId)
select 1, null
union all
select 1, 2
union all
select 1, 3
union all
select 2, null
union all
select 2, 5
union all
select 5, 6
union all
--select 6, 5
--union all
select 6, 8

declare @id int = 2

;with MyCTE as (
    select ParentId, ChildId
    from @test
    where ParentId = @id

    union all

    select t2.ParentId, t2.ChildId
    from MyCTE t1
    inner join @Test t2 on t1.ChildId = t2.ParentId
)

select * from MyCTE
```

Another thing I didn't understand is why do you have such rows where `ChildId` is null and `ParentId` is not null. How can it be possible?

Does it mean that you have unknown items whose parent is known?

Comment: the ChildId is null to specify that particular row is that of the parent. More like it is the root node.

Comment: If it is a root node then the parentid should be null and childid should be filled. A root cannot have a parent, but it will have children.