# MS SQL select statement with "check table"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling to find out a solution for my select statement. I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Things
(
  Id int, 
  type int
)

CREATE TABLE Relations
(
  Id int,
  IdParent int,
  IdChild int
)
```

What I need to select, based on given Thing Id:

- All records from Things that has `Type = -1`
- All records from Things that has `Type` matching `IdChild` where `IdParent` is Type of a row matching given `Id`.
- If `Type` of a row matching given `Id` is `-1` or doesn't exist in table Relations (as IdParent) I need to select all records from Things

I am having problem with the last scenario, I tried to do that by joining Relations table, but I can't come up with a condition that would satisfy all scenarios, any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

This is how I do it now. I need to solve the scenario where given id does not exists in table Relations - then I need to select all records.

```
CREATE TABLE Things (id int, type int)
CREATE TABLE Relations (id int, parent int, child int)

INSERT INTO Things VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO Things VALUES (2, -1)
INSERT INTO Things VALUES (3, 3)
INSERT INTO Things VALUES (4, 3)
INSERT INTO Things VALUES (5, 2)
INSERT INTO Things VALUES (6, -1)

INSERT INTO Relations VALUES (1, 1, 2)

DECLARE @id int = 1

SELECT * FROM Things
JOIN Relations R ON R.parent = @id AND Type = R.child OR Type = -1
```

So I must solve the situation where @id = 2 for example - I need to retrieve all rows (same for @id = 5, unless it appears in Relations in parent column somewhere).

**UPDATE 2**

I came up with something like that:

```
DECLARE @id int = 2
DECLARE @type int

SELECT @type = type FROM Things WHERE Id = @id

IF @type > -1
BEGIN
SELECT T.* FROM Things T
JOIN Relations R ON (R.parent = @id AND T.Type = R.child) OR T.Type = -1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Things
END
```

I'm quite sure that this can be done differently, without conditional IF, optimized.

Comment: Can you provide an data example of your raw data and what you like to receive? I'm promise you get a working query back ;)

Comment: What is the relationship between `Things` and `Relations`?

Comment: is this the kind of thing you're after, for retrieving a parent and it's children: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25551203/57475

Comment: Show how you are doing 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
 from Things
 left outer join Relations 
   on Relations.IdParent = Things.Type 
where Things.Type = -1 or Relations.IdParent is null
```