# Using hierarchyId in Parent Child relation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named **tb_Section**. It is designed to support n-level hierarchy. Each row has a **ParentSetionId** that points to another row's **SectionId** in case of a Parent/Child relationship.

Now, I have a process where I have to copy these sections one by one to another table keeping the hierarchy intact. I arranged the section by Using order by as follows:

```
Select 
 s.SectionId,
 s.ParentSectionId,
 s.SectionName
From 
 tb_Section s
Where
 s.TemplateId = 123
Order By
 Convert(hierarchyid, '/' + cast(sec.ParentSectionId as varchar)+ '/')
```

I insert these in a TempTable and Insert each section one by one in another table. This was working fine. But after the application went live an issue was reported.

A user firstly created all the sections as Parent Sections and then one by one edited them and made them child of other sections(Used the most difficult way :/) The section hierarchy was as follows:

```
Super-Parent
      Parent1
          Child1
          Child2
      Parent2
          Child3
          Child4
```

The above query in this case returns the following rows in order.

```
SuperParent
Child1
Child2
Parent1
Child3
Child4
Parent2
```

Instead of the normal case, which should be this

```
SuperParent
Parent1    
Child1
Child2
Parent2
Child3
Child4
```

Any help regarding this? I can't seem to find the reason why this is happening.

**UPDATE**

Here is the SQL Script where Children are inserted first.

```
CREATE TABLE tb_Section(
   SectionId BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,ParentSectionId BIGINT 
  ,SectionName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO tb_Section(SectionId,ParentSectionId,SectionName) VALUES (SectionId,ParentSectionId,N'SectionName');
INSERT INTO tb_Section(SectionId,ParentSectionId,SectionName) VALUES (686772,686776,N'Child 1');
INSERT INTO tb_Section(SectionId,ParentSectionId,SectionName) VALUES (686773,686776,N'Child 2');
INSERT INTO tb_Section(SectionId,ParentSectionId,SectionName) VALUES (686774,686777,N'Child 3');
INSERT INTO tb_Section(SectionId,ParentSectionId,SectionName) VALUES (686775,686777,N'Child 4');
INSERT INTO tb_Section(SectionId,ParentSectionId,SectionName) VALUES (686776,686778,N'Parent 1');
INSERT INTO tb_Section(SectionId,ParentSectionId,SectionName) VALUES (686777,686778,N'Parent 2');
INSERT INTO tb_Section(SectionId,ParentSectionId,SectionName) VALUES (686778,NULL,N'Super-Parent');
```

Here is the result my above query returns with **hierarchyId**

```
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
| SectionId | ParentSectionId | SectionTypeId | SectionName  |   hierarchy    |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
|    686778 | NULL            |             1 | Super-Parent | NULL           |
|    686772 | 686776          |             2 | Child 1      | 0xF800298C6620 |
|    686773 | 686776          |             2 | Child 2      | 0xF800298C6620 |
|    686774 | 686777          |             2 | Child 3      | 0xF800298C6660 |
|    686775 | 686777          |             2 | Child 4      | 0xF800298C6660 |
|    686776 | 686778          |             2 | Parent 1     | 0xF800298C66A0 |
|    686777 | 686778          |             2 | Parent 2     | 0xF800298C66A0 |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
```

You can see that the hierarchy is different, here child items are showing before the Parents. I hope this sample data helps.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: A sample of raw table data would be useful

Comment: why not use a hierachid type https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select statement to return parent and infinite children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550850/select-statement-to-return-parent-and-infinite-children)

Comment: @SteveFord I am using the hierarchyId in my order by statement, but the hierarchyId only works properly when data is inserted in a tree like form. Here leaf nodes are added first as a Parent nodes and later changed to become leaf-nodes.

Comment: @ZunairZubair see recursive answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a recursive CTE and create your own hierarchy string:

```
;WITH Recurs
AS
(
    SELECT SectionId, ParentSectionId, 
           SectionName, '/' + CAST(SectionId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as Level
    FROM tb_Section
    WHERE ParentSectionId Is NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.SectionId, s.ParentSectionId, s.SectionName, 
           CAST(r.level + '/' + CAST(s.SectionId AS VARCHAR(MAX) )AS Varchar(MAX))
    FROM tb_Section s
    INNER JOIN recurs r
        ON S.ParentSectionId = r.SectionId
)
SELECT *
FROM Recurs
ORDER BY Level
```

Produces:

```
SectionId   ParentSectionId SectionName  Level
686778      NULL            Super-Parent /686778
686776      686778          Parent 1     /686778/686776
686772      686776          Child 1      /686778/686776/686772
686773      686776          Child 2      /686778/686776/686773
686777      686778          Parent 2     /686778/686777
686774      686777          Child 3      /686778/686777/686774
686775      686777          Child 4      /686778/686777/686775
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. But in terms of large data, wouldn't CTE be slow?

Comment: @ZunairZubair it may be slow for large queries, if you know there are only ever going to be 3 levels then you could accomplish the same with JOINS and UNIONS

Comment: I have n-level hierarchy. But its working fine at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

From the data that you've provided, the HierarchyID value looks incorrect to me. When I run this query:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_Section(
   SectionId BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,ParentSectionId BIGINT 
  ,SectionName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , h HIERARCHYID
);

INSERT  INTO [tb_Section]
        ( [SectionId], [ParentSectionId], [SectionName], [h] )
VALUES  ( 686778, NULL, 'Super-Parent', NULL ),
        ( 686772, 686776, 'Child 1', 0xF800298C6620 ),
        ( 686773, 686776, 'Child 2', 0xF800298C6620 ),
        ( 686774, 686777, 'Child 3', 0xF800298C6660 ),
        ( 686775, 686777, 'Child 4 ', 0xF800298C6660 ),
        ( 686776, 686778, 'Parent 1 ', 0xF800298C66A0 ),
        ( 686777, 686778, 'Parent 2 ', 0xF800298C66A0 );

SELECT [ts].[SectionId] ,
       [ts].[ParentSectionId] ,
       [ts].[SectionName] ,
       [ts].[h].ToString()
FROM [dbo].[tb_Section] AS [ts]
ORDER BY h
```

The values for the "Child N" values look don't show any connection back to the Super-Parent. So let's run the following update:

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[tb_Section]
SET     [h] = CONCAT('/686778', h.ToString())
WHERE   [SectionName] LIKE 'Child%'
```

We're getting better, but now if we run the select from the previous step again, the results are coming back based on hierarchy depth. That is, the Super-Parent is coming back first, then the Parents, and then finally the children. Which, when you look at the string value of the hierarchy still makes sense; all of the Parent rows have the same hierarchy value and so they'll be sorted together.

One final update should get you to where you want to go:

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[tb_Section]
SET     [h] = CONCAT(ISNULL(h.ToString(), '/'), [SectionId], '/')
```

Now, when you run that same select again, the sub-hierarchies are sorted together. So the TL;DR on this one is that the HierarchyID needs to provide a full path from the source (in your case, Super-Parent) down to destination (in your case, Child), inclusive.