# Recursive sql - find the grandgrandparent of a child

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query, ancestor

I have a table like the below:

`Id ParentID
1     99
2     9
3     1
4     2
5     4
6     3`

and I would like to have a query that gives me for each child the last ancestor.

I mean that the desired result is

`id     Lastancestor
 1      99
 2      9
 3      99
 4      9
 5      9
 6      99`

I have a lot of data so I need something quick.

Thanks.

Comment: What you need is a [Recursive Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: and an example from the excellent help at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909692/sql-server-cte-parent-child-recursive

Comment: Is there a maximum depth?

Comment: `99`? Do you have a plan for handling deities, or just use a magic number for their (single) parent? How about NULL? Or zero? Or, just to be difficult, their own `Id`? Have you done any research or made any attempts at solving your problem? The idea here is that people help you solve problems, but SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Xristos Epitropakis You would need to change your data (and i understand you probably cant do this) but the HIERARCHYID data type in T-SQL is designed for this sort of thing. Have a read of this if your interested https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**Recursive CTE**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) to accomplish this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Id AS origId, ParentID, 0 AS lvl
  FROM mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT c.origId AS origId, 
         m.ParentID, lvl = lvl + 1
  FROM CTE AS c
  INNER JOIN mytable AS m ON c.ParentID = m.Id
)
SELECT origId AS id, ParentID AS Lastancestor
FROM (
  SELECT origId, ParentID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY origId 
                            ORDER BY lvl DESC) AS rn
  FROM CTE) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Here, the *anchor member* of the CTE is just the whole table. Recursion goes up the tree hierarchy while propagating the original `Id` (as `origId`) down the recursion chain. The recursion terminates as soon as an empty set is returned, i.e. as soon as no more `c.ParentID = m.Id` matches are found.

To get the required result, i.e. the `Lastancestor` per `id`, all we need to do is fetch the record having the *greatest* `lvl` (i.e. depth) per `id`. This is achieved using `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7309b/6)

Comment: Very nice solution! +1 from my side

Comment: One question: Did you use this approach in **real life**? I really appreciate it, but - as the OP stated - there's "lot of data" and it must be "quick". If the CTE is filled with a large table, this recursion will lead to many, many full table scans. I doubt, that there is usage of an index... What is your experience with this? Anyway, I love it and have to do some tests...

Comment: @Shnugo This is the preferred approach to query hierarchical data structures in SQL Server. The only other alternative AFAIK is the use of a cursor which is less efficient. I have never used recursive CTEs in real life though. The OP can inform us about how it performs with his actual data.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a maximum depth you could use this approach. You can add further depth levels with simple copy and past and adapt. I added one data element "19,6" to generate one with three ancestors and one with four.

Just paste this into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs...

```
declare @Test table (Id int, ParentID int)

insert into @Test values
(1,99)
,(2,9)
,(3,1)
,(4,2)
,(5,4)
,(6,3)
,(19,6);


WITH Ancestors1 AS
(
    SELECT Test.*
          ,Ancestor.ParentID AS Anc1ID 
    FROM @Test AS Test
    LEFT JOIN @Test AS Ancestor ON Test.ParentID=Ancestor.Id
)
,Ancestors2 AS
(
    SELECT Ancestors1.*
          , Ancestor.ParentID AS Anc2ID 
    FROM Ancestors1
    LEFT JOIN @Test AS Ancestor ON Ancestors1.Anc1ID=Ancestor.Id
)
,Ancestors3 AS
(
    SELECT Ancestors2.*
          , Ancestor.ParentID AS Anc3ID 
    FROM Ancestors2
    LEFT JOIN @Test AS Ancestor ON Ancestors2.Anc2ID=Ancestor.Id
)
SELECT Id,*
      ,COALESCE(Anc3ID,Anc2ID,Anc1ID,ParentID)  AS LastAncId
FROM Ancestors3
```